# Docker 'run' command to start apache

Tags: docker

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-apache2:latest
```

Unable to find image 'my-apache2:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository my-apache2 not found: does not exist or no pull access.

P.S. It works with Nginx(docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:latest), I can see the image using docker ps

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following. (Ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/ )

```
docker run -p 80:80 -d httpd:latest
```